# Asserting URL path and its ID dynamically using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, url, cypress

So I wrote a method in Cypress using Regular Expressions that will dynamically assert any pathname and its ID I pass the following way:

```
public assertUrlPathWithID(path:string) {
cy.url().should("match", /\/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\/(\w|0-9)*/);
};
assertUrlPathWithID("customerdetails")
```

The test is passing, but I was was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing it or a different approach that is more effective.  Essentially, I want to assert that the url path using regex for the routes on my application

```
/customerdetails/id
/customer/id
/order/id
```

Comment: for a match only, you can omit the capture group, and if you intend to match `[0-9]` at the end, that is what `\w` also matches `\/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\/\w+` Note that the pattern matches at least 3 chars with `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: @Thefourthbird is there a way to match it, regardless of the number of chars in it?

Comment: If you don't want to match consecutive hyphens, and using a case insensitive pattern `/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\/\w+/i` See https://regex101.com/r/G0x9BF/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `(\w|0-9)*` seems like an unintended repetition as `0-9` matches that literally. If you want to match a digit the notation could be `[0-9]` but that is also matched by `\w`

Using a case insensitive pattern with `/i` where the part of the pattern matches at least 3 characters, and using `\w+` to match 1 or more word characters (at the id seems to be always present)

```
/\/[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\/\w+/i
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f6Co2p/1)

If you also want to match a single character, and no consecutive hyphens `--`

```
/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\/\w+
```

The pattern matches:

- `\/[a-z0-9]+` Match `/` and 1+ chars a-z0-9
- `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat `-` and 1+ chars a-z0-9
- `\/\w+` Match `/` and 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G0x9BF/1)

Answer (score 4):

Typically URL routes will be of format `/<resource>/<numeric-id>`

A `<resource>` would originate in javascript, and probably needs to follow the rules for javascript variables

> **Naming variables in JavaScript**
>
> - Variable names must start with a letter, an underscore ( _ ) or a dollar sign ( $ ).
> - Variable names cannot contain spaces.

which gives regex of

```js
/\/([a-z|$|_][a-z|\-|\d]*)\/(\d+)/i
```

Breaking it down,

`<resource>`

- `[a-z|$|_]` handles first char requirement
- `[a-z|\-|\d]*` handles subsequent chars. Conventionally `-` is allowed in a variable name

`<numeric-id>`

- `(\d+)` because only digits should be in the `id`

`/<the-regex>/i`

- ignore-case modifier removes the need for `[A-Z]` in the regex

**Test**

This is the test in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZNgLX9/1)

```js
// these should pass
/customerdetails/1
/customer/2
/customer/321
/order/555
/_product/234
/$orderitem/345
/$order-item/345
/$order1-item/345
/$/1

// these should fail
/order/a12
/5product/123
/$order item/432
/-order/123
```

---

If you want a more relaxed approach, this could be the simplest regex:

```js
\/\w+\/\d+
```